# Convert csv files into a single JSON (w/ arrays) using Python

Tags: python, json, sas

I have been trying to convert 3 csv files with related keys into a single JSON file using Python.

Originally, I had tried using SAS but noticed the proc required (I believe) all data to be available in a single row.  I was unable to recreate an array containing multiple customers or warehouses against a single sale.

The challenge I am facing is the 1st csv is a unique set of data points there are no duplicates.  The 2nd csv links back to the 1st via and this creates duplicate rows, this is the same for the 3rd csv.
The 3rd csv is a 1 to many relationship with the 1st and the 2nd csv has a 0 to 1 to many relationship with the 1st.

The format of the 3 csv files is as follows:

**CSV 1 - single row for each unique ID**

| saleID | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

**CSV2 - can have duplicates 1 to many relationship with csv1**

| WarehouseID | saleID | WarehouseName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 2 | B |
| 1 | 3 | A |

**CSV3 - can have duplicates 1 to many relationship with csv1**

| customerID | saleID | CustomerName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Albert |
| 2 | 2 | Bob |
| 3 | 1 | Cath |

The expected format of the JSON would be something like this.

```
{
"totalSales":2,
"Sales":[{
    "saleId":1,
    "productName":"A",
    "warehouse":[{
        "warehouseID":1,
        "warehouseName":"A"
    }],
    "customer":[{
        "customerID":1,
        "customerName":"Albert"
    },
    "customerID":3,
        "customerName":"Cath"
    }],
"Sales":[{
    "saleId":2,
    "productName":"B",
    "warehouse":[{
        "warehouseID":2,
        "warehouseName":"B"
    }],
    "customer":[{
        "customerID":2,
        "customerName":"Bob"
    }]
 }
```

What i've tried so far in python seems to have a similar result as what i achieved in SAS as i think im missing the step to capture the warehouse and customer information as an array.

```
def multicsvtojson():
salesdf = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Python\\multiCSVtoJSON\\sales.csv', names=("salesID","ProductName"))
warehousedf = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Python\\multiCSVtoJSON\\warehouse.csv', names=("warehouseID", "salesID", "warehouseName"))
customerdf = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Python\\multiCSVtoJSON\\customers.csv', names=("customerID", "salesID", "customerName"))

finaldf = pd.merge(pd.merge(salesdf, warehousedf, on='salesID'), customerdf, on='salesID')

finaldf.to_json('finalResult.json', orient='records')

print(finaldf)
```

results
[{"salesID":"saleID","ProductName":"productName","warehouseID":"warehouseID","warehouseName":"warehouseName","customerID":"customerID","customerName":"productName"},
{"salesID":"1","ProductName":"A","warehouseID":"1","warehouseName":"A","customerID":"1","customerName":"Albert"},
{"salesID":"1","ProductName":"A","warehouseID":"1","warehouseName":"A","customerID":"3","customerName":"Cath"},
{"salesID":"2","ProductName":"B","warehouseID":"2","warehouseName":"B","customerID":"2","customerName":"Bob"}]

Comment: Why is there a SALEID in CSV2 that is not in CSV1?

Comment: Your expected JSON text does not look valid.